# How to manupulate Python unittest output '.' , E and F

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

Python unittest give '.', E or F on ok, error or fail. We can avoid it by setting verbosity = 0, or /dev/null. but how can we change it. I mean I want to write after every test PASS, FAIL or ERROR instead of ., E or F, without using verbosity flag -V for output.

I am looking for following kind of output:

1. test one
   PASS
2. test two
   FAIL
3. test three
   PASS
4. test four
   ERROR

Thanks
Zubair

Answer (score 5):

So using extra verbosity (`-v`) on the command line gets the desired output format:

> Passing the -v option to your test script will instruct `unittest.main()` to enable a higher level of verbosity, and produce the following output:

> ```
> test_isupper (__main__.TestStringMethods) ... ok
> test_split (__main__.TestStringMethods) ... ok
> test_upper (__main__.TestStringMethods) ... ok
>
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> Ran 3 tests in 0.001s
>
> OK
> ```
>
> (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example)

But we can also set the verbosity level from code:

> You can run tests with more detailed information by passing in the verbosity argument:

> ```
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     unittest.main(verbosity=2)
> ```
>
> (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.main)

If you want to further customize the output, see [Stef's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73544819/248065).

Comment: Thanks, But I was thinking to somehow manipulate/change the above (verbosity 2) output.

Comment: I doubt that is possible without hacking the source code / massively overriding `unittest`'s test runners etc.

Comment: you may be able to get away with using `sed` to transform the output, if you are using tools to parse `PASS`, `FAIL` etc (which I assume you're doing, otherwise your question doesn't make a lot of sense).

Comment: @ThomWiggers no hacking required and overriding is rather straightforward as the methods are well [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html), see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73544819/3944322)

Comment: cool, I wasn't aware of `TextTestRunner`.

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own test runner and result class to customize almost everything. If you just want to change the output of the test names (just the method name without the class) and change `ok` to `PASS` it's enough to override the [`startTest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult.startTest) and [`addSuccess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult.addSuccess) methods of the standard `TextTestResult`:

```
import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_pass(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_fail(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)

    def test_error(self):
        x = 1 / 0


class MyTestResult(unittest.TextTestResult):

    def __init__(self, stream, descriptions, verbosity):
        super().__init__(stream, descriptions, verbosity)
        self.stream = stream
        self.verbosity = verbosity

    def addSuccess(self, test):
        if self.verbosity > 1:
            self.stream.writeln("PASS")
        else:
            super().addSuccess(test)

    def startTest(self, test):
        unittest.TestResult.startTest(self, test)
        if self.verbosity > 1:
            self.stream.write(f"{test._testMethodName} ")
            self.stream.flush()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(testRunner=unittest.TextTestRunner(resultclass=MyTestResult, verbosity=2))
```

Output:

```
test_error ERROR
test_fail FAIL
test_pass PASS

======================================================================
ERROR: test_error (__main__.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in test_error
    x = 1 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

======================================================================
FAIL: test_fail (__main__.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in test_fail
    self.assertTrue(False)
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1, errors=1)
```

instead of the standard output:

```
test_error (__main__.Test) ... ERROR
test_fail (__main__.Test) ... FAIL
test_pass (__main__.Test) ... ok
...
```